# That hologram effect from Star Wars

Tags: animation, texturing, uv, effects, shader-nodes

So I’m trying to recreate the Princess Leia hologram effect from Star Wars. I’ve got the interlacing and transparency down. But I’m trying to nail that flicker as well as the way it glitches out/dissolves at the end.

https://youtu.be/0RDIJfoBhFU

[image: hologram effect]

Comment: try using displace modifier with subsurf and a cloud or something texture to make the glitch and for flicker effect in your material do this: add a white noise 1D feed it to a math node with greater than then apply it to your stripes or whatever part that need to flicker

Comment: Much easier than I thought it was gonna be, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

As mma78 says, you can give your object a *Displace* modifier with *Texture Coordinates > Object* and with an empty as object, give it a *Texture > Clouds*, then scale the empty on Z. For the flickering light, play with the factor of the second *Mix Shader*, you can keyframe and give it a *Modifier > Noise* in the *Graph Editor*:

[image]

You should also put additional noise like a *Wave Texture*, etc:

[image]

You can even make the beam:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for taking the time to do this mock up in blender! That’s awesome! Appreciate all your input!